# Excelファイルを操作すると時々破損します。

Tags: delphi

現在、仕事の関係にてExcelファイルの内容を自動で書き換えるプログラムを作成していますが、
その前段階にて該当のExcelファイルにマクロが含まれているか判定する様にしています。

そのマクロの判定段階で該当のExcelファイルが破損する事があります。(2019年8月辺りから月に1000ユーザー中5件程度発生し始めている)
原因の検討が付かず困っている状態です。

また、破損したファイルをExcelで開こうとすると、「原紙名:ファイル形式が正しくありません。」とのメッセージが表示され開く事や修復も出来ない状態です。

下記にOLEを操作して、Excelファイルのマクロ有無を判定するコードをお伝えいたします。
Excelファイルのマクロ判定には、Delphi言語にて行っております。

---

**Excelファイルのマクロ判定コード**

```
function MacroCheck(gensi: string): boolean;
var
   PrnFileName:array[0..255] of Char;
   i: Integer;
begin
   strpcopy(PrnFileName, gensi);
   try
      if XlsOpenBook(PrnFileName, nil, i) then begin
         XlsAddSheet(1);
         if not XlsDelSheet(0,XlsGetSheetCount-1) then begin
            //マクロ有り
            Result := True;
         end
         else begin
            //マクロ無し
            Result := False;
         end;
      end
      else begin
         Result := False;
      end;
   finally
      XlsCloseBook(False);
   end;
end;
```

Comment: DelphiでC#の`using`に相当する機能があるかどうか知りませんが、この記事と類似のことが起こっているのかもしれません。ただし、違っていたらごめんなさい。[C#でAccessを使用した後の終了方法について](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/59257/26370), [How do I properly clean up Excel interop objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/158706/9014308), [Closing an Excel Workbook](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17440138/9014308) あとマクロ有効無効は拡張子でも分かりそうですが。[Word、Excel、PowerPoint のファイル形式リファレンス](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/deployoffice/compat/office-file-format-reference)

Comment: @sayuri さんの指摘が合っているなら、[このヘルプ](http://www.adv.co.jp/download/download-confrm.php?skey=31&ftype=H)に **「また、本製品は、Excel オブジェクトを使用せず、独自の技術により Excel ファイルの読み書きを行っているため、MS-Excel がインストールされていない実行環境で、高速な処理を実現することができます。」** とありますね。

Comment: @kunif  さんご指摘ありがとうございます。合わせて検討させてください。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XlsOpenBook / XlsCloseBookなどの名称から[ExcelCreator API](http://www.adv.co.jp/product/product_excelcreator3_creatorapi.htm)が使われていると見受けられます。

OLEもExcelも使用されていないようですので、環境を確認し、ExcelCreatorが使われているのであれば製造元に問い合わせるべきです。